# CSS3 shapes and animation - Arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

As shown in the image below, I have to create this image and animate it. I was planning not to actually use an image for this but rather do this using CSS3 `border-radius`. So, the below HTML and CSS is where I'm at.

The animation I want is that the arrow should start appearing from the bottom and moving up along the flow keeps on showing, take a right with flow till the end with arrow pointer. But I am really not sure how can I do this. I have to support browser IE8+, chrome, FF.

HTML:

```
<div class="years">
    <article>
        <figure>
            <div class="vrt-bar"></div>
            <div class="hrzt-bar"></div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </figure>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.years article figure {
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.years article figure .vrt-bar {
    width:34px;
    height:192px;
    behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);
    border-radius:25px 0 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px 0 25px 25px;
    float:left;
    background:#00b9d3;
    position:relative;

}
.years article figure .hrzt-bar {
    width:143px;
    height:32px;
    background:#00b9d3;
    margin-left:34px;
}
.years article figure .arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #00b9d3;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:177px;

}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KgAe4/

Can anyone please help on this?

[image]

Comment: So your basic need is the animation right now, according to the jsfiddle?

Comment: Volker, that's right. Am just not sure how to do that.

Comment: CSS3 Transitions/Animations aren't fulfilling your needs here, as you have to support IE8.
The most critical point in my understanding is the arrow going along the corner in upper-left. I guess that you'd have to go for a layer with the full arrow (already there) and another layer on top with a background hiding the not yet animated parts and the arrow that is changing position.
Animation of the the corner with border-radius seems pretty time-consuming.

Comment: Well, I could leave the flow animation for the extreme right top pointer i.e. class "arrow", but I would still need the animation for the vrt-bar first and then the top hrzt-bar.

Comment: Or even if it needs changing html/css, that would be okay as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try this 
I guess anyone  of the below is what you need

### Working **[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/KgAe4/10/)**

I have edited your css a little,
and the code

```
$('.arrow-up').animate({
    'top': '-5px'
}, 1000, function () {
    $(this).addClass('arrow').removeClass('arrow-up');
    $('.arrow').animate({
        'left': '177px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

### or

Another Type is here

I have edited your css a little,
and the code

### Working [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/KgAe4/52/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.arrow-up').animate({
        'top': '-10px'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).addClass('arrow').removeClass('arrow-up');
        $('.arrow').animate({
            'left': '177px'
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('.vrt-bar').animate({'height':'192px'},1000,function(){
    $('.hrzt-bar').delay(80).animate({'width':'143px'},1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: Well, I was actually looking for the whole arrow, not the arrow pointer (i.e. class "arrow") to animate from the bottom (i.e. starting from bottom of class "vrt-bar" till top and then taking a right with starting from class "hrzt-bar" till its end, then class "arrow"). But DEMO1 looks interesting as well, sure it does, just that is there a way to animate the arrow pointer i.e. class "arrow" from bottom to top and then left to right. In your case, its just moving from left to right. If this works, I think I might be able to convince my client. Thanks for showing a different direction on this.

Comment: Oh, I just now realised that in your DEMO1, the class "arrow" is already moving from bottom to top, then from left to right, its just that it was very fast while moving till top, hence it appeared so. Anyhow, I am going to check if that solution works. Thanks again.

Comment: @whyAto8, I have also upadetd the DEMO1 ,with slow animation, check this out

Comment: sorry the OP didn't accept the answer +1 for a good answer and because it should have been accepted.